# Idle connections after update to django 4

Tags: django, postgresql

We were using Django 3.2 and before the update everything was fine, but now, after the update to 4.0 we have a problem with too many open database connections. We getting errors like this:
`FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections.`
We using CONN_MAX_AGE=60, but connections are sometimes not closed at all.

```
Django 4.0.8
Daphne 4.0.0
channels & channels-redis 4.0.0
DB: postgresql 11/14
```

`CONN_MAX_AGE=0` works well, but it is probably not the best option for efficient production. I also set the environment variable `ASGI_THREADS=1`, but nothing changed, we still have dozens of idle connections. I was also trying to replace Daphne with Gunicorn + Uvicorn and remove Django channels from the codebase, but nothing helped. I know that we can extend the number of available connections, but if old connections are not closing, then soon or later we will hit each limit.

Comment: Hi, Marcin, have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered the same issue today. We are using Gunicorn + Uvicorn. This is after an upgrade to Django 4. The libraries listed are the same version or slightly newer. Only happens to us in production.

Update: We decided to downgrade Django to v3 until we figure this out. On v3 it all seems to work just like it did on v2 before we upgraded.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution already? Same issue here.

Comment: @humanbeing We are still on Django v3 and did not attempt to upgrade to v4 since. It blew up in out face big time when we tried that. The redis stability got a lot better, and I believe we have almost all libraries on latest version (redis-py, channels and related packages). I can tell you the exact versions if it helps you. There were still some issues, but works sufficiently in production.

Comment: Thanks, exact versions are not needed. I was just curious if you fixed the issue as support for django 3.2 will end next year. I'm still trying to make it usable on django 4.2.